# Wireless range extender - caused my networked devices to stop working

Tags: wireless-networking

I got a WD My New wireless range extender. I configured it to use the same SSID as my main wireless router and the same security. 
After I turned it on, for some reason my Dell wireless printer wouldn't print and my phone would have issues connecting to WiFi. Another wireless printer at home gave me a warning that it found two SSIDs that are the same.
As soon as I unplugged the range extender everything started working without any issues.
Am I missing something? What can I do to have my devices work better?
Should I use a different SSID for the extender?

Thanks!

Comment: [My Net Wi-Fi Range Extender User Manual](http://www.wdc.com/wdproducts/library/UM/ENG/4779-705081.pdf) tells you how it should be set up.

Comment: Set it up according to the manual.